# Turning a pulse into an extended on signal

Tags: signal, raspberry-pi, pulse

I have a device which outputs pulses at 5V. I want to detect these pulses with my Raspberry Pi later. The problem is that my Raspberry Pi script will be doing other things that take time, and I'm worried that it will not be able to pick up on the pulses (it will not check the state of the GPIO pin when the pulses occur).

Is there some way to take 5V pulses and not only turn them into a solid logical on, but also extend the length? My dream would be that whenever the pulses happened, I could have a 3.3V signal be on for a minute or so.

Comment: An extended pulse might cover up a possible second or third pulse; is that tolerable?

Comment: Typically I would use an edge triggered interrupt and the code clears the interrupt when it gets around to it

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231280/how-to-turn-a-pulsed-signal-into-a-continuous-one/309266#309266

Comment: some answers there: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231280/how-to-turn-a-pulsed-signal-into-a-continuous-one/309266#309266

Comment: you can buy cheap "timer relay" modules to do just that. i like 555-based solutions as well...

Answer (score 2):

For a software solution: use interrupts http://wiringpi.com/reference/priority-interrupts-and-threads/

As a bonus: Extending a short pulse can be accomplished using a monostable circuit like this: 
http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/555/imagesP1/555-one-shotPosTrig.gif