# Is there a component that will OR the last 1-2ms of its input?

Tags: 555, integrator, edge

I need a component/circuit which will output 1 if a 1 has been input at any time in the last 1-2ms.

I could make such a circuit out of several shift registers, an oscillator and several OR gates, or I could use an MCU.

Is there a simpler (maybe analogue) alternative?  I've considered:

```
bus -->|--+--+-- out
          |  |
          =  R
          |  |
          _  _
          -  -
                           _
>| diode    = capacitor    - GND    R resistor
```

but the 1V diode drop is quite big, making the circuit very sensitive to the bus being driven at less than 3V3.  There may be slew issues, with the output component not recognising an edge.

Maybe a 555 can do this?

The required logic looks like:

```
       _                          ____   _   __
bus __| |________________________|    |_| |_|  |______________________
       _____________________      _________________________________
out __|                     |____|                                 |__

        |<----- 1-2ms ----->|                  |<----- 1-2ms ----->|
```

Comment: A 555 sure, but today we have more. eg: LTC6994 (which is basically the mcu you mention, but the hard part has been done already)

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `one-shot`, i.e. a rising edge (1) triggers the one-shot to maintain its output of 1 for a duration of 2ms. Would that meet your requirement?

Comment: The ASCII art is lovely but there's a schematic button on the editor toolbar that does a better job. When finished hit the "Save and Insert" button and an image is posted in your question with an edit link. No CircuitLab account required.

Comment: @MarkU A monostable multivibrator isn't quite what's needed.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monostable shows the output going low, even when the input is still high.  I'll add a diagram to my post.

Comment: @Transistor I did that, and clicked "Save and Insert" but nothing happened except for a brief circular timer.  I then tried the back button, which took me back to the editor but without the circuit.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Thanks, an LTC6994-1 has a mode which will do exactly what I want. https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6994-1-6994-2.pdf  On the downside, it's $1.35 and needs programming.

Comment: The LTC6994 is programmed by a few resistors. But I see now you need a Turn Off Delay.

Comment: [Retriggerable and non retriggerable monostables](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231280/how-to-turn-a-pulsed-signal-into-a-continuous-one/231292#231292)

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks, I now see that I not only need a retriggerable monostable vibrator, but one where the trigger is the high level, not the rising edge.  Is there such a thing as a level-triggered retriggerable monostable vibrator?  (The first page of Google is not very useful.)

Comment: The circuit at the bottom of my answer in the link above will do what you want from what I can tell.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks, that waveform matches what I want.  (Did you change your link - I followed it before, but don't remember seeing that.  Apologies.)  Are you sure that the waveform diagram is right?  It's at odds with "a re-occuring pulse fed to the input (the little circle to the left in front of the two resistors feeding a BJT) keeps the 555 from timing out.".  That would put the 10s starting at the last rising edge, not the final falling edge.

Comment: @fadedbee yes I changed the link when I realized that I had made an answer that had a circuit. The wave form is correct, it waits for another 10 seconds after the pulse disappears i.e. it keeps re-triggering while ever the pulse is present. It's a level detection circuit and the transistor keeps the capacitor discharged while ever the input pulse is high. The little circle is just a termination point and not an inversion.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks, if write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @fadedbee done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a re-triggerable monostable and this can be made from a 555 timer. Waveform: -

[image]

555 circuit using a BJT to keep the timing capacitor discharged: -

[image]

Comment: First time I've seen the 555 drawn with an amplifier symbol, huh!

Comment: @Hearth maybe I can find a better one?

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with it. It's just a bit odd to see.

Comment: Probably drawn by Picasso! No, he'd use a cube d'oh.

Comment: The regular 555 won't work at 3.3 V, will it?

Comment: [TLC555 - 2 volts to 15 volts](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf?ts=1591188346292) @Transistor